# How to perform in Ecto 2.0 custom select query in Repo.preload by JSON attribute?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, postgresql-json

I have Post with category and many tags through tagging, tags and category contains hstore `name` filed that contains translations in keys.

How to preload related `post.tags` and select JSON `tag.name` with for example "pl" key by pure Ecto query? I would like to pass locale key in this case "pl" as param, but I don't know how to interpolate it, nothing works.

```
defmodule Myapp.Tag do
  use Myapp.Web, :model

  schema "tags" do
    field :name, :map

    has_many :taggings, Myapp.Tagging
    has_many :posts, through: [:taggings, :post]

    belongs_to :post, Myapp.Post
    timestamps
  end
end

defmodule Myapp.Tagging do
  use Myapp.Web, :model

  schema "taggings" do
    belongs_to :post, Myapp.Post
    belongs_to :tag, Myapp.Tag
  end
end

defmodule Myapp.Post do
  use Myapp.Web, :model

  schema "posts" do
    field :title, :string

    belongs_to :category, Myapp.Category
    has_many :taggings, Myapp.Tagging
    has_many :tags, through: [:taggings, :tag]
    timestamps
  end
end
```

Test:

```
post = Repo.get!(Post, id) |> Repo.preload([:tags, :category])
post.tags # => "tags":[{"name":{"pl":"narty","en":"ski"}},{"name":{"pl":"wspinaczka","en":"climbing"}}]

#how preload all with selected key?

posts = Post 
  |> Repo.all 
  |> Repo.preload(tags: from(t in Myapp.Tag, select: fragment("?::json->?", t.name, "pl")))
```

Error:

```
** (BadMapError) expected a map, got: "narty"
    (stdlib) :maps.find(:id, "narty")
    (elixir) lib/map.ex:27: Map.fetch!/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1387: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1043: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.map/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1387: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1043: Enum.map/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1043: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.map/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1387: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1043: Enum.map/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:669: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:438: :erl_eval.expr/5
       (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:117: IEx.Evaluator.handle_eval/5
```

I would like:

```
post.tags # => "tags":["narty","wspinaczka"]
```

Migrations:

```
defmodule Myapp.Repo.Migrations.CreateTag do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:tags) do
      add :name, :map
      add :category_id, references(:categories)

      timestamps
    end

  end
end

defmodule Myapp.Repo.Migrations.CreateJoinTableTaggings do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:taggings) do
      add :post_id, references(:posts)
      add :tag_id, references(:tags)
    end
    create index(:taggings, [:post_id, :tag_id])
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

Ecto 2.0 supports custom select field in preload queries, so this is the answer:

```
|> Repo.preload(tags: from(t in Myapp.Tag, select: %{id: t.id, data: fragment("?::json->?", t.name, "pl")}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to filter the tags using the Enum.map function.

```
Repo.get!(Post, id) |> Repo.preload([:tags])
|> Map.get(:tags)
|> Enum.map(&(&1.name.pl))
```

This is the same, just different syntax:

```
Repo.get!(Post, id) |> Repo.preload([:tags])
|> Map.get(:tags)
|> Enum.map(fn(tag) -> tag.name.pl end)
```

Returns a list 
`["narty", "wspinaczka"]`

Comment: I thought about solution with Ecto query in Post model, get in first step post in standard way and then by custom preload function select name with "pl" key, if possible I would like to avoid processing extracted list in pipe operators chain.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is by using the `Ecto.Query` module and using an Ecto query.

It's a bit different though from the Repo.preload approach so I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for exactly.

Based on the previous many-one datamodel:

```
query = from(from t in MyApp.Tag, where: t.post_id == ^id, select: t)
Repo.all(query) |> Enum.map(&(&1.name.pl))
```

Based on the newer many-many datamodel as edited, this should be closer:

```
post_id = "some_id" # <-- enter your id here
query = Ecto.Query.from tagging in MyApp.Tagging,
        join: tag in assoc(tagging, :tags),
        where: tagging.post_id == ^post_id,
        select: tag
Repo.all(query) |> Enum.map(&(&1.name.pl))
```

Can you try something along these lines...
I'm not sure if it will work or not as I have no way to run it, the json fragment query may need to be modified..

```
Repo.all(
  from tagging in MyApp.Tagging,
  join: tag in assoc(tagging, :tags), 
  where: tagging.post_id == ^post_id, 
  select: fragment("?::json#>'{?,?}'", tag, ^"name", ^"pl")
)
```

Comment: I can't get hstore key just by dot after name: `** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) 't.name().pl()' is not a valid query expression`

Comment: can you put the migration file into the original post for the Myapp.Tag schema? I'm wondering what the postgresql data type is for the :name field which is a map.

Comment: it seems that your solutions with Enum.map is correct at the moment [github](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/1205), my idea will be supported in echo 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can override an `Ecto.Association` (i.e) `:tags` but however you can filter on preload and map the value.

```
Repo.get!(Post, id) |> Repo.preload(tags: from(t in Tag, where: t.name == 'pl'))
```

Check the [documentation](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/2) for more details.